# Encoding a PHP properties file in UTF-8

Tags: php, eclipse, utf-8, preg-replace, properties-file

I have a properties file that I'm reading in PHP. The property looks something like this:

```
destination = "bibliothèque"
```

Then, I want to read the property as UTF-8.

```
function utf8_trim($str) {
    return preg_replace("/^[\p{Z}\p{Cf}\x{200e}\x{200f}\s]*([\s\S]*?)[\p{Z}\p{Cf}\x{200e}\x{200f}\s]*$/u", "$1", $str);
}

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$places = parse_ini_file($filename);
$destination_untrimmed = $places['destination'];
$destination = utf8_trim($destination_untrimmed); //FAILS on this step due to invalid encoding
```

I am using Eclipse 3.8.1. How can I input my string into the constants file as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ini file is not utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types. Need more?

Comment: its not for me its for the asker :)

Comment: I know, but thanks :-) I was supposed to write a little better answer ;-)

Comment: @secretformula: thanks for asking for the elaboration, as I indeed needed it. :)